# How to make php display \t \n as tab and new line instead of characters

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm trying to output the data in my php file as plain text and I want the output to have a table format like this:

```
data1    data2    data3
1        a        b
2        c        d
....
```

When i try this:

```
foreach(...)
echo $data1 . '\t' . $data2 . '\t' . $data3 . '\n';
```

it prints them as `data1\tdata2\tdata3\n...`

How can I get php to read `\t` and `\n` as tab and new line?

Comment: after using double quotes the output becomes `data1 data2 data3` it's still not reading them as new line and tab

Comment: Are you viewing in a browser? HTML output collapses whitespace. View the output using the command line or send `header('Content-Type: text/plain');`. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/HI7jss

Comment: @cbuckley yah i was testing it in browser, it works now after setting the header. thanks :)

Comment: I think it's far better to consider using a define once a for all as double quotes may create security issues… Thus why not do something like : 
define('PHP_TAB',"\t"); // || define('PHP_TAB',' ');
echo PHP_TAB.'TAB'.PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_TAB.'TAB'.PHP_EOL;

Answer (score 57, accepted):

put it in double quotes

`echo "\t";`

See: http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: And do NOT forget to add `header('Content-Type: text/plain');`. Won't work without it in the browser.

Comment: Doesn't work with `error_log("\t");`. Any quick help?

Answer (score 41):

```
"\n" = new line
'\n' = \n
"\t" = tab
'\t' = \t
```

Comment: [Manual link](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Answer (score 6):

`"\t"` not `'\t'`, php doesnt escape in single quotes

Answer (score 4):

Put it in double quotes:

```
echo "\t";
```

Single quotes do not expand escaped characters.

Use the [documentation](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.single) when in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML,

```
foreach(...)
echo $data1 . '&nbsp' . $data2 . '&nbsp' . $data3 . '<br/>';
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if your strings are random numbers they are not perfectly aligned.